# Dependency Errors upgrading to Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-upgrade

I remove my Gemfile.lock, change my `gem 'rails', '5.2'` to `gem 'rails', '6.0'` and do bundle install.

I get a lot of dependency errors. But I cannot understand them because they seem okay.

I was getting errors like this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "pry":
  In Gemfile:
    guard-rspec (~> 4.7.0) was resolved to 4.7.3, which depends on
      guard (~> 2.1) was resolved to 2.16.2, which depends on
        pry (>= 0.9.12)

    pry-doc was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      pry (~> 0.11)

    pry-nav was resolved to 0.3.0, which depends on
      pry (>= 0.9.10, < 0.13.0)

    pry-rails was resolved to 0.3.9, which depends on
      pry (>= 0.10.4)
```

and a lot more.. seems in the above that the dependencies should be fine, i.e. 0.11 for pry-doc is greater than all the others and they all specify greater than or equal.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out specifying the exact latest version of rails fixed the problem.

originally in my Gemfile I had:

`gem 'rails', '6.0'`

but when I did

`gem 'rails', '6.0.3.6'`

and bundle install, I got no such dependency errors